# How do I make a ruby string "\("?

Tags: ruby, escaping

I needed a ruby string with `"\("` in it and found the escaping playing trick on me.

`"\("` gives me `"("`
`"\\("` gives me `"\\("`

Comment: `"\\("` is actually correct for the double quoted style.  You're just getting the result of `inspect` back when in the REPL: Try `puts "\\("` to see what I mean

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`"\\("` is correct, the problem is that the result of [`inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-inspect) (which is what IRB uses to display the return value of the last call) is not the same as the actual contents because of the escaping:

```
puts "\\(".inspect  #prints: "\\("
puts "\\("          #prints: \(
```

If you don't need interpolation, just use single quotes:

```
puts '\('  #prints: \(
```

Comment: This is a source of a lot of confusion. If you read `"\("` as *backslash, open-bracket* or *literal-bracket* and `"\\("` as *literal-backslash, bracket* then it makes more sense. Ruby, Python, JavaScript, Perl, C, bash and many others use this escaping method. It pays to know your [backslash escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Backslash_escapes)!